# How to completely dump the data for Django-CMS

Tags: database, django, django-cms

I have an instance of Django-CMS already running in a production environment.  I would like to dump all the data related to the CMS (PAGES and PLUGINS) so that I may load it back into my development environment.

When I do `python manage.py dumpdata cms` it dumps most of the data, but not all of it.  None of the content for the plugins is dumped.  When I look at the django-cms source, I see that the plugins are organized in a different folder than the rest of the models - I'm sure this has something to do with the behavior of `dumpdata`.

Does anyone know how they would achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks for your help/answers!

Comment: If you are using app hooks you should probably export the data from them, and related to them, models too.

Answer (score 18):

Django's built in dump and restore commands work well for migrating the contents of the CMS.

To dump the contents of the CMS, you need to include both the cms app as well as each of the plugin types you are using in the dumpdata command, so something like:

```
manage.py dumpdata cms text picture link file [other plugin types] > cms_export.json
```

to dump your content (you just need the app name, not the full path, like `cms.plugins.text`).

Comment: you might want to use --indent=4 so you can better read the output and see if there is something missing, or edit it.

Comment: Also, if you want to be both lazy and accurate at the same time - use the cms command for listing the used plugins to determine which ones you actually need like so: 

    python manage.py cms list plugins

This will only show the plugins in use - and thus ones that actually have content that needs to be exported.

Comment: This will also be more important with CMS 3.0 where the plugins have moved/been renamed and are no longer a part of the CMS app.

Answer (score 12):

Here's an update to the procedure I use:

```
./manage.py dumpdata >fixtures/all.json

psql
DROP DATABASE [DBNAME];
createdb -T template_postgis [DBNAME]

./manage.py syncdb

psql [DBNAME]

delete from auth_group_permissions; delete from auth_permission; delete from django_admin_log; delete from django_content_type;
```

If you don't delete the tables above you'll get this error when loading the fixtures:

```
IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint django_content_type_app_label_key
```

And then:

```
./manage.py loaddata fixtures/all.json
```

Philipp

Answer (score 4):

For DjangoCMS 3.0, the syntax is the same but the names of the plugins have all changed.  To get all standard plugins:

`./manage.py dumpdata cms djangocms_column djangocms_file djangocms_flash djangocms_googlemap djangocms_inherit djangocms_link djangocms_picture djangocms_style djangocms_teaser djangocms_text_ckeditor djangocms_video > cms_export.json`

Answer (score 2):

Your `dumpdata` command only dumps the data for the `cms` app, but each plugin (`cms.plugins.text`, `cms.plugins.picture`, etc.) is its own app, and so needs to be added to the command line.

Comment: `python manage.py dumpdata cms.plugins.text` generates the following result:


`Error: Unknown application: cms.plugins.text`


Even though I do have this listed as one of my installed applications in my main settings.py and the application is functioning correctly.

Comment: Could you please show a working example of the dumpdata command that you use? (thanks)

Comment: Err, no, but I don't use Django-CMS. You might want to try asking in `#django` on Freenode.